# Check if menu has a location assigned

Tags: wordpress

How can I check if a menu has been assigned to a menu location. Let me get this straight:

I'm getting all menus created by using `wp_get_nav_menus()` and after I get the menus I'm getting their items by using `wp_get_nav_menu_items()`.

So I get something like this: 
**Primary Menu** 
Menu item 1 
Menu item 2 
Menu item 3

But now I want to check if **Primary Menu** has a location assigned, and if it is not assigned to a location, then don't print it.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `get_nav_menu_locations()` to get an array of registered menu locations and the menus assigned to those locations.

You'd then simply check the ID of `Primary Menu` in your example against the array. If a key exists for the value then it has a location assigned.

Example:

```
$nav_menus      = wp_get_nav_menus();
$menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

/** 
 * Validate here... skipping for the purpose of answering the
 * question at hand. Would be a good idea to make sure the functions
 * above returned the values we were expecting.
 */

// Here I'm guessing you're simply looping through menus.
foreach ( (array) $nav_menus as $nav_menu ) {

    /** 
     * array_search will tell us if the menu's 'term_id' property
     * matches any of the values in the locations array. In actual
     * fact it gives us the key but that's not necessary here.
     */
    if ( array_search( $nav_menu->term_id, $menu_locations ) ) {

        // menu has a location - output here...

    }

}
```

References: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_nav_menu_locations/

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: Thanks for this!